# Deploy a container application for every user that register

Tags: docker, nginx, kubernetes, docker-swarm

So I have an application. So I want to deploy that application using a separate docker container for every user that signs up. I also want them to be deployed on a different subdomain for e.g.

1. if my domain is https://example.com I want to deploy https://x.example.com
2. if x sign up and https://y.example.com if y sign up.
   I want these deployments to be done after a user finishes the signup process and deletes them if a user chooses to deregister themselves. Also, the database for these users will be different but should be manageable using a centralized mechanism.
   **What is the best approach for this type of application?**

Comment: How big a cluster will you require if you have 100 users?  Or 1000?  How will you update the respective deployments as code changes?  A single multi-tenant application seems much more maintainable.

Answer (score 1):

**These kind of dynamic deployments are not natively supported by K8s.** However, you can build something yourself, by creating an application that has sufficient RBAC permissions on the API-Server on the Deployment resource, as well as functionality to create those deployments. Furthermore, it exposes a REST-API that can be called within your cluster to trigger those deployments on demand.

A while ago, I created a Github project to illustrate how it is done: [k8scrud](https://github.com/fritzduchardt/k8scrud). Please feel free to use it as inspiration or directly.